# giving access to online shop by selecting value from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a website using php and mysql which allows users to create an account and upload medical documents then an admin will review the data which has been uploaded by the users and has the option to approve or not approve the user. What i am trying to do now is when a user has been approved from the admin they will be given access to a mini shop by displaying a button only if the user has been approved.

```
<?php
$sql_con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '' , 'medical_db');

if($stmt = $sql_con->prepare("SELECT approved FROM users WHERE approved = Approved")) {

   $stmt->bind_param("s", $approved);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->bind_result($approved);

   while ($stmt->fetch()) {

     echo '<a href="products.php">store access</a>';
   }
   $stmt->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: Your SQL doesn't have a place holder for the bind variable, I assume you wanted `approved = ?`

Comment: i want to check if there is approved or not approved in the database and based on that display a button to give access to a shop

Comment: What would stop a non-approved user from going to `products.php` and access your store? So you better make this into a function, you can reuse, or use a session/cookie.

Comment: you can show an example please as i'm really stuck on this and i have been trying different things but noting works

Comment: Look again at what Nigel Ren said, and read the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). It's all there.

Comment: approved is always approved

Answer (score 0):

Your query says `WHERE approved = Approved`. It's possible it should say `WHERE approved = 'Approved'` instead, because your `users.approved` column is most likely a `VARCHAR()` column.

You didn't ask about patient confidentiality. I'm sure you know the laws protecting patient confidentiality are [draconian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draconian) in most countries. Please be careful.